# difference between innodb_log_buffer_size and innodb_buffer_pool_size

Tags: mysql, innodb

Difference between `innodb_log_buffer_size` and `innodb_buffer_pool_size` in mysql? Is the `innodb_log_buffer_size` is given out of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`. What data do `innodb_log_buffer_size` and `innodb_buffer_pool_size` contains.

Comment: You didn't use google, did you?

Comment: @N.B. i did it. But what i found that innodb_log_buffer_size is used while transaction commit and innodb_buffer_pool_size is used for storing index, table meta data. but i could not find  "Is the innodb_log_buffer_size is given out of innodb_buffer_pool_size". And something more about innodb_buffer_pool_size (where they are used an d what they contains.). thanks.

Comment: OP - might be worth clarifying, are there aspects of the details available on the MySQL doc sites that you would like a bit of help understanding?

Comment: @Brian "The size in bytes of the memory buffer InnoDB uses to cache data and indexes of its tables." This is what is given in mysql site but i want to know what other things get stored in this. And more importantly "Is the innodb_log_buffer_size is given out of innodb_buffer_pool_size".

Comment: buffer pool is the amount of memory (RAM) that InnoDB is allowed to use to cache active data set (indexes etc.) to make various queries quick. The log buffer is amount of memory reserved to log queries grouped in a transaction. Every second InnoDB will try to flush data from log buffer to the hard drive. So if you have lots of queries, InnoDB will save them to log buffer much quicker than to write each one to the disk. This value doesn't have to be high (8MB is more than enough), while buffer_pool one is desirable to be large. More info on both is available at MySQL website.

Comment: @N.B. Is the innodb_log_buffer_size is given out of innodb_buffer_pool_size?

Comment: No, none are given out of anything, you set them up yourself. Both of them. They have nothing in common, why would one yield another?

Answer (score 10):

I found the following explanation:

> "The `innodb_buffer_pool` is the memory buffer that InnoDB uses to cache data and indexes of its tables. The larger you set this value, the less disk I/O is needed to access data in tables. You may set this to up to 50% of the machine physical memory size. However, do not set it too large because competition for the physical memory might cause paging in the operating system, or even out of memory problems.

The `innodb_log_file_size` is the size of the transaction log. By default there are two logfiles. The preferred value size for the log_file_size is 25% of the `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.

The size of the `innodb_log_buffer_size` that InnoDB uses to write to the log files on disk. A large log buffer allows large transactions to run without a need to write the log to disk before the transactions commit. If you have big transactions, making the log buffer larger will save disk I/O. This value should be 32Mb."